# Is there a way I can reload textures or have a hotkey for updates in shader editor?

Tags: shaders

I'm doing all my texturing in substance painter.  When I export the textures into the same location and replace the file names I've been using for the texture nodes in blender, they don't update automatically.

I guess Blender doesn't refresh it because it doesn't have a way of knowing the texture has been updated.  I've been just reloading my entire blend file.  There must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Turn on the Node Wrangler Addon and put the mouse on the Texture node and press ALT + R

Comment: @Emir You should give that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the Node Wrangler Addon (edit > Preferences) and put the mouse on the Texture node and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!!  Although this isn't really what I wanted, system limitations I guess!

I wanted it to just update automatically when it detect a change file. But maybe I'm being too lazy. :)